# Renumbering the \part in Exam class

Tags: numbering, exam

I just want one section to be renumbered, not all the `\parts` numbering.

I have found this in the manual:

```
\renewcommand{\thepartno}{\Roman{partno}}
```

But that is making all the numbering for `\part` to be Roman.

I can't find in the manual where to just have it renumber for a certain section.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\renewcommand{\thepartno}{\Roman{partno}}

\begin{document}
\smallskip
\begin{questions}
\question Which of the following is continuous at $x = 0$ ?
\begin{center}
    \begin{parts}
    \part $f\left(x\right) = \vert x \vert$
    \part $f\left(x\right) = e^{x}$
    \part $f\left(x\right) = \ln\left(e^{x} - 1 \right)$
    \end{parts}
\end{center}
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice I only
\choice II only
\choice I and II only
\choice II and III only
\choice none
\end{oneparchoices}

\begin{solution}
\end{solution}
\vspace{\stretch{2}}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of adding quotes to the code lines, just select the whole code block and press Ctrl-K or click on the `{}` icon above the box.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use

```
\renewcommand{\thepartno}{\Roman{partno}}
```

inside the `parts` environment to keep the change local:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{exam}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question Which of the following is continuous at $x = 0$ ?
    \begin{parts}
\renewcommand{\thepartno}{\Roman{partno}}
    \part $f\left(x\right) = \vert x \vert$
    \part $f\left(x\right) = e^{x}$
    \part $f\left(x\right) = \ln\left(e^{x} - 1 \right)$
    \end{parts}
\question Which of the following is continuous at $x = 0$ ?
    \begin{parts}
    \part $f\left(x\right) = \vert x \vert$
    \part $f\left(x\right) = e^{x}$
    \part $f\left(x\right) = \ln\left(e^{x} - 1 \right)$
    \end{parts}
\end{questions}


\end{document}
```

[image]

As a side note, you can use the `\label`, `\ref` mechanism to avoid manual numbering:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{exam}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question Which of the following is continuous at $x = 0$ ?
    \begin{parts}
\renewcommand{\thepartno}{\Roman{partno}}
    \part\label{abs} $f\left(x\right) = \vert x \vert$
    \part\label{exp} $f\left(x\right) = e^{x}$
    \part\label{log} $f\left(x\right) = \ln\left(e^{x} - 1 \right)$
    \end{parts}
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice \ref{abs} only
\choice \ref{exp} only
\choice \ref{abs} and~\ref{exp} only
\choice \ref{exp} and~\ref{log} only
\choice none
\end{oneparchoices}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How did you get the code to be all together?

Comment: @MaoYiyi I am afraid I don't understand your question. Can you please rephrase it? (English is not my native tongue, so I don't understand it as it is now.)

Comment: @MaoYiyi: I've corrected it in your original post. If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://goo.gl/VPzfr). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with `{}` on it).

Comment: @MaoYiyi Ah, now that I see Werner's comment, I understand the question. Werner himself has provided the answer.

Comment: @MaoYiyi I added to my answer some recommendation about using `\label`, and `\ref` that you might find useful.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Esta pasao

Comment: with "\renewcommand{\thepartno}{\alph{partno}}" I get a. I want a) or (a) for \part numbering. How do I get that?

Comment: ok I figured this out from the examdoc documentation.