# How can I resume the part numbering in exam document class?

Tags: numbering, lists, exam, parts

For `enumerate` there are options like [`start`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170/128042) or [`resume`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1670/128042) or commands like [`\setcounter{enumi}{4}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149/128042) or [`\addtocounter{enumi}{41}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150/128042) as discussed in questions like [How can I make an enumerate list start at something other than 1?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/142/128042) or [Resuming a list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1669/128042).

Are there analogous possibilities for the `parts` environment in the `exam` document class?

```
\documentclass{exam} 

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question[10]
Some not indented text
\begin{parts}
    \part this should be (a)
    \part this should be (b)
\end{parts}
Some more not indented text interrupting the parts
\begin{parts}
    \part this should be (c)
    \part this should be (d)
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\setcounter{partno}{3}` or `\addtocounter{partno}{5}` are possibilities <sub>(inspired by https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/81720/128042)</sub>, but a bit less elegant than the automatic [`resume` option for `enumerate`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1670/128042).

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1702/128042 would be slightly less hard codes but a bit more code:

```
\documentclass{exam} 
\newcounter{nameOfYourChoice}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question[10]
Some not indented text
\begin{parts}
    \part this should be (a)
    \part this should be (b)
    \setcounter{nameOfYourChoice}{\value{partno}}
\end{parts}
Some more not indented text interrupting the parts
\begin{parts}\setcounter{partno}{\value{nameOfYourChoice}}
    \part this should be (c)
    \part this should be (d)
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```